# Android Xamarin C#: Get the number of satellites used for GPS location

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gps, satellite

I want to find the number of satellites that my gps is using but no matter what I do it always returns 0.
I have googled and read a lot about people with the same or similar issue but none of the fixes seemed to work for me. It would still only return 0.

Here is my function:

```
    private static int TotalSatillites(Android.Locations.LocationManager locationProviders)
    {
        var gpsStatus = locationProviders.GetGpsStatus(null);
        var satilliteIterator = gpsStatus.Satellites.Iterator();

        var totalSatillies = 0;
        while (satilliteIterator.HasNext)
        {
            var satillite = (GpsSatellite)satilliteIterator.Next();
            if (satillite.UsedInFix())
            {
                totalSatillies++;
            }
        }

        return totalSatillies;
    }
```

AFAIK This should work but doesn't appear to and I cannot figure out why.
I have also tried using locations Extras like so:

```
var sats = location.Extras.GetInt("satellites");
```

But this also only ever comes back 0.

Note: I am testing this entirely in the android emulator and I am setting the location via telnet with the command:

```
geo fix 9 9 9 9
```

Which should set lat and long to 9, altitude to 9 and satellites to 9. This (should be?) working as my code gets the 9's for lat long and alt first and then tries to get the satellites numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the short answer to this question is for you to use `LocationManager.RequestLocationUpdates` with a `minTime` = 0 and a `minDistance` = 0, so it fires off an `OnGpsStatusChanged` event quickly. Here is a simple application that should demonstrate what I mean:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Util;
using Debug = System.Diagnostics.Debug;

namespace App24_Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App24_Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, GpsStatus.IListener, ILocationListener
    {
        int count = 1;
        private LocationManager locationManager = null;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            locationManager = (LocationManager) GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            locationManager.AddGpsStatusListener(this);
            locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 0, 0, this);

            GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.GetGpsStatus(null);
            if (gpsStatus != null)
            {
                IIterable satellites = gpsStatus.Satellites;
                IIterator sat = satellites.Iterator();
                string lSatellites = null;
                int i = 0;
                while (sat.HasNext)
                {
                    GpsSatellite satellite = sat.Next().JavaCast<GpsSatellite>();
                    Debug.WriteLine(satellite.Prn);
                }
            }


            button.Click += delegate
            {
                button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);

            };
        }

        public void OnGpsStatusChanged(GpsEvent e)
        {
            GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.GetGpsStatus(null);
            if (gpsStatus != null)
            {
                IIterable satellites = gpsStatus.Satellites;
                IIterator sat = satellites.Iterator();
                string lSatellites = null;
                int i = 0;
                while (sat.HasNext)
                {
                    GpsSatellite satellite = sat.Next().JavaCast<GpsSatellite>();
                    Debug.WriteLine(satellite.Prn);
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {

        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
        {

        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
        {

        }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I tested this on a physical device by simply turning off my wifi and ensuring my location services are on.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I tried to implement your answer into my code but it still comes back as 0, on the sat.HasNext  line it will always say the iterator has no next and skip the while block.

Comment: I'm not sure of the specifics of using `geo fix`, as I mentioned I had only tested this on a physical device. There is further documentation on mock data here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData Otherwise you can try seeing if your emulator provides that type of functionality through a location GUI (The new Android SDK tools 25.1+ ones have this functionality built in) - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html I would personally recommend that you invest in an Android device for testing location/maps/etc as it's easier.