# How to get the number of satellites for Xamarin Android project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on the Xamarin Android project and I need to get the information of how many satellites (not accuracy and other workarounds).
I found a solution below, however, the GpsStatus.IListener is obsoleted.
[Android Xamarin C#: Get the number of satellites used for GPS location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538504/android-xamarin-c-get-the-number-of-satellites-used-for-gps-location)
I also tried FusedLocationProviderClient, but I couldn't see satellites information gets returned.
Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Even a third party library helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `GnssStatus` instead.

`GnssStatus`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.locations.gnssstatus?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12

Add the code below in `OnCreate` method:

```
 LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
        mLocationManager.RegisterGnssStatusCallback(new GetSatellites());
```

GnssStatus.Callback:

```
 public class GetSatellites : GnssStatus.Callback
{
    public int satelliteCount;
    public override void OnSatelliteStatusChanged(GnssStatus status)
    {
        base.OnSatelliteStatusChanged(status);
        satelliteCount = status.SatelliteCount;
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------"+satelliteCount);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add the permission.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: One more question, can we get the number of satellites without the status change?

Comment: @DennisL - its inherently an asynchronous operation, so you are going to have to write code accordingly. It should give you the first callback with only a brief delay - you could modify the answer with an action to be called the first time it calls back. After that, the current satellite count is maintained in your code, as shown by Wendy.

Comment: @DennisL You could use the callback to return the count like Steve said. If you have any issue about this, feel free to let me know.